# gulp.dest is not working for gulp useref

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-useref

I'm trying to use gulp useref to merge my bower js files, app js files and css but its not working for me. My dest directory is always empty when i run gulp command

Here is my directory structure which is generated using yomean

```
   app
      bower_components
      main
      img
   dest
   gulp
   hooks
   node_modules
```

This is my index.html

```
<!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="main/main.js"></script>
<script src="main/constants/config-const.js"></script>
<script src="main/controllers/badge.controller.js"></script>
<script src="main/controllers/creation.controller.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

My gulp.js looks like this

```
gulp.task('useref', function(){
     return gulp.src('app/main/*.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'),{relative: true});
   });
```

useref task runs fine as i see it in my terminal console but for some reason dest directory does not have resultant file in it

Comment: Your paths seem to be wrong. Is your index.html located in main/? If so, then your script tags have the wrong path. If your index.html is in app/, then gulp.src is incorrect.

Comment: @dannyjolie my index.html is located in app, can you please tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: You have gulp-inject commands in your html file. Remove it, this does not make sense in a gulp-useref area.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was all rev issues.  Remove all local versions and -g versions of gulp-useref and make sure your local package.json devDependencies sections is list gulp-useref^3.0.0

```
  "devDependencies": {
      "gulp-useref": "^3.0.0",
      .  .  .  .  
  }
```

then from project home
    npm up --dev

I also updated gulp-cli and gulp to 4.0 while I was at it.  I am a newbee so how will I every know if this is a mistake or not.

takes a while but it ended a day of fruitless head pounding with a satisfying result and bowl of Ben&Jerry's ice cream